# Vba copy and paste specifc cells if criteria is met

Tags: vba, rows, copy-paste

I'm trying to copy and paste the cells in each row C through F if the value in column C is greater than 0. Please help thanks!

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim range1 As Range
Dim Cell As Object
Set range1 = Sheet1.Range("C8:C40")

For Each Cell In range1
    If IsEmpty(Cell) Then
        End If
    If Cell.Value > 0 Then
    Sheet1.range(C:F).Copy
    Sheet5.Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("A40").End(xlUp).Select
    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    End If
    Next
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the row that is being tested.

Also do not use `.Activate` or `.Select` It only slows down the code.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim range1 As Range
Dim Cell As Range
Set range1 = Sheet1.Range("C8:C40")

For Each Cell In range1
    If Cell.Value > 0 Then
        With Sheet1
            .Range(.Cells(Cell.Row,"C"),.Cells(Cell.Row,"F")).Copy Sheet5.Range("A40").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        End With
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

---

To do it with just the values, no formatting, Change this:

```
.Range(.Cells(Cell.Row,"C"),.Cells(Cell.Row,"F")).Copy Sheet5.Range("A40").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
```

To:

```
Sheet5.Range("A40").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(,4).Value = .Range(.Cells(Cell.Row,"C"),.Cells(Cell.Row,"F")).Value
```

Comment: Thank you. What expression would give me the values without any of the formatting?

Comment: @Philip see edit, remember that if this works to mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: How exactly does the offset function work, I want to another similar table right by its side (same height wand width)

Comment: `Offset(Rows,Columns)`  it uses a range the same size as the parent range offset the number of columns and rows supplied to the function.  Google `Range.Offset vba` for more information.

Comment: How would I get them to stack instead of going side by side. It seems to only be letting me do two tables across.